# How to add an onchange event to select tag and have the select tag also have option siblings using mithril.js

Tags: javascript, html, mithril.js

I don't know how to add an event and sibling elements to an element.

example of what I have now:

```
m('select', [
  ctrl.countries().map(function(d, i){ 
    return m('option', { onclick : ctrl.country_add.bind(group, group.countries),  value : d.iso2, innerHTML : d.Name })
    console.log(d,i);
  })
])
```

and an example of what I thought could work but didn't.

```
m('select', { onchange : function(){alert('this')}},[-
  ctrl.countries().map(function(d, i){ 
    return m('option', { value : d.iso2, innerHTML : d.Name })
    console.log(d,i);
  })
])
```

I hope it' clear what my intentions are. Notice that the onclick event is removed in example two and a onchange event added to it's parent element "select".

Comment: You have a `-` at the end of line 1... maybe thats the problem?

Comment: That is a space in my vim.

Comment: Ok, do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The second snippet works just fine?

```
m.render(document.body, [

m('select', { onchange : function(){ alert('this') }},[
  [1, 2, 3].map(function(d, i){ 
    return m('option', { value : d, innerHTML : d })

  })
])

]
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3eshvafc/

Comment: If you change the `'this'` string to `this.value`, the selected value will  pop out. Just in case, that's not obvious to you.

Comment: This is the solution. After fiddling, somehow the issue has resolved itself. I cannot find the reason why. Stephen Hoyer, thnx for the hint!